# Can't ssh into my ubuntu vps

Tags: 12.04, ssh, openssh, putty, vps

I have a vps running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I have installed openSSH but I can't connect to it with putty. I get error saying Network error:Connection timed out. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Telnet to port 22 of your VPS. If sshd is accepting connections, you should see something similar to the following:

```
$ telnet your.vps.foo 22
Trying 203.0.113.25...
Connected to your.vps.foo.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1

Protocol mismatch.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

If you aren't getting that response from the vps, you may have a firewall blocking the port, or a configuration problem in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

- `man sshd_config` explains how that file file works